# Can I use dynamically LIKE and IN together?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to be able to say :

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE accountName LIKE('%john%', '%bill%', '%lory%'.....)
```

I want that to be dynamically, which means depend on user input the list of '%name%' parts will be different. One time could have 3 names and another probably just 1.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT myTable.*
FROM myTable
JOIN (SELECT '%john%' UNION ALL
      SELECT '%bill%' UNION ALL
      SELECT '%lory%') sub(c)  -- this could be anything table variable/temp
  ON myTable.accountName LIKE sub.c;
```

Keep in mind that '%...%' is not SARG-able.

With table variable:

```
DECLARE @tab AS TABLE (c NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tab(c) VALUES ('...');
-- ...

SELECT DISTINCT myTable.*
FROM myTable
JOIN @tab t
  ON myTable.accountName LIKE t.c;
```

Comment: I am confused how is this dynamic. How would I do it since I don't know the number of names included on the search. For me the input will be a string with 1 or more names. I will have to split that in multiple names and than pass it as an query argument for my sql query.

Comment: @DoArNa The dynamic part is in temp table. It will search based on record you insert into`@tab`. It could be 1,2, or more.

Answer (score 2):

> WHERE accountName LIKE('%john%', '%bill%', '%lory%'.....)

This is invalid syntax and won't work. The easiest way to do what you're trying to do would be to use a "string splitter" function like [Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(1000) = 'john, bill, lory';

SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    dbo.myTable mt
    CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@Names, ',') dsk
WHERE 
    mt.accountname LIKE '%' + dsk.Item + '%';
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    dbo.myTable mt
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@Names, ',') dsk 
            WHERE mt.accountname LIKE '%' + dsk.Item + '%'
            );
```

HTH, Jason

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Jason and Lad's very excellent solutions you could speed things up with an indexed view.

*Before I continue - it's important to note that this will slow down inserts/updates/deletes in high-traffic OLTP environments that modify these tables often. TEST, TEST, TEST!.*

I work in the Data Warehouse world where this works out quite nicely.

First a keyword table for common search terms:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.keyword (kw varchar(100) not null, constraint uq_keyword unique clustered(kw));
INSERT dbo.keyword VALUES ('john'), ('bill'), ('lory');
```

Next for your table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.mytable(someid int identity not null, accountname varchar(100));
INSERT dbo.mytable(accountname) VALUES 
('John''s Flowers'), ('Candles by Bill'), ('Some other account'), ('The Lory Group LLC');
```

Now the view along with a couple important indexes:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_mytable_fastKWLookup
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS -- schemabinding required for indexed views
SELECT 
 t.someid,
 t.accountname,
 k.kw 
FROM dbo.mytable t
CROSS JOIN dbo.keyword k
WHERE t.accountname LIKE '%'+k.kw+'%';
GO

-- required unique clustered index
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX uq_cl_vw_mytable_fastKWLookup 
  ON dbo.vw_mytable_fastKWLookup(kw, someid);

-- A good nonclustered index
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc_vw_mytable_fastKWLookup__kw
  ON dbo.vw_mytable_fastKWLookup(kw) include (someid, accountname);
```

Once your indexed view is in place you can add your search words to an in list like so:

```
SELECT someid, accountname, kw 
FROM vw_mytable_fastKWLookup WITH (NOEXPAND)
WHERE kw IN ('John', 'Lory', 'Bill', 'Fred');
```

Results:

```
someid      accountname          kw
----------- -------------------- -----
1           John's Flowers       john
2           Candles by Bill      bill
4           The Lory Group LLC   lory
```

The reward here is an execution plan that does a non-clustered index seek for %searchstring% style searches.

[image]